# a process tries to chmod a file while another process has already been wrting to that file?

Tags: android, c, filesystems

Suppose,

at timeA, the 1st process(P1) creates a file and begin writing to it, and after some time,

at timeB, the 2nd process tries to chmod the file permission. And, after some time,

at timeC, P1 finishes writing and closes the file.

The question is: at what time point can other process(say P3) observe that the file permission has been changed?

The file system is inside Android, which should be Linux file system.

I didn't find any document or specification addressing this concurrency issue.

Comment: What behaviour do you expect? And which behaviour did you discover trying this out?

Comment: you can remove a file while writing on it. I'd say that write keeps working until the file is closed. needs to be tested, though.

Comment: @greenapps  sorry for my not making question clear.  I have updated my question.  Please help to take a look again. thank your help.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre sorry for my not making question clear. I have updated my question. Please help to take a look again. thank your help.

Answer (score 1):

In POSIX semantics which Linux tries to follow, the [file access permissions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_04) are only checked when opening the file. After the process has an open file descriptor, the process can continue use those permissions the file descriptor was granted until the process closes the file descriptor.

It is also possible for a process to have an open file descriptor to a file that it didn't open, or never had permissions to open - the file descriptors can be inherited over fork and exec, and they can also be sent via Unix domain sockets.

Concurrency-wise there is only one thing: either the `open` happens before or after the `chmod` takes effect. If before, then the process writing into file can be completely oblivious that `open` happened.

Comment: sorry for my not making question clear. I have updated my question. Please help to take a look again. thank your help.